# Determinant of ray transfer matrix

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Quick question on the wikipedia entry for the *ray transfer matrix*, which is defined :

[image]

where $x$ is the distance of a point from the optical axis and $\theta$ the angle that the beam profile at that point makes with the optical axis.

Now, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_transfer_matrix_analysis#Definition_of_the_ray_transfer_matrix) says:[image]

but does NOT provide a reference.

Does anyone have any idea on how to get that results? Do you know a website/paper where this is discussed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why they say a thermodynamics argument is needed. [Here](http://physics.ucsd.edu/neurophysics/courses/physics_173_273/Phys_173_optics.pdf) is a tutorial on basic optical design that shows it from Snell's law and simple geometry.

Comment: the cited tutorial doesn't even leave a word on the determinant of the ray matrix.